# How to reload autofs on Lion without restarting?

Tags: services, macos

I'm trying to get my host machine running Lion to automount an NFS export on my CentOS VM.

I was able to get this working on a system running Mac OS 10.5 by modifying `/etc/auto_master` and then restarting the `autofs` service per the instructions in http://alanlam.blogspot.com/2008/06/restart-autofs-in-leopard-without.html:

> ```
> sudo service com.apple.autofsd stop
> sudo service com.apple.autofsd start
> ```

However, in Lion, the `service` command appears to be missing.

How do I reload the `autofs` service in OS X Lion without restarting?

Comment: Does launchtcl show the com.apple.autofsd as a job that is loaded? Launchd really should be controlling this for you and logging why and when a halt / respawn or error happens.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

this works for me:

```
sudo automount -vc
```

Comment: Forgot about that; thanks!  I like this better, since it is a 'reload' operation rather than a 'restart'.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `launchctl` instead of `service`:

```
sudo launchctl stop com.apple.autofsd
```

You should not need to restart autofsdt manually; launchd will notice that it has stopped, and immediately start another instance.

Comment: this works under Catalina (10.15).